# How can I use a dynamic value for MongoDB $inc operator?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I want to update the stock of the products when someone purchases with $inc operator. But the example in MongoDB showed how to use $inc with a static value.

Is there any way so that I can send the value from the client side to the server side? I am building the project with React.js, Node.js and MongoDB
[mongodb example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECt3I.png)

Comment: Simply put your input value into the query

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0):

You could simply pass the input in parameters of your api call.

```
app.post('/product', (req, res) => {
  const result = await ProductModel.updateOne({
    metrics: {
       $inc: {
         quantity: req.body.incrementCount
       }
    }
  })
})
```